# Use I as an variable in Maple

Tags: maple

I want to declare a function I(t), but Maple interprets I as the imaginary unit. Can I use a Maple command to assume I is an variable? I've looked in the manual, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: You could try using capital $\iota$ (Iota) instead.

Comment: The other one where I occasionally get into trouble is `D` used as a name.  It is used for some derivatives...

Comment: I really like the capital Iota idea. A variation is `interface(imaginaryunit= Iota)`. That way you only have to type one letter for variable I, and the appearance of imaginary I remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

Maple 17, but not older Maple, will allow `local I` at the top level. But the following will work in any Maple: First pick some symbol other than `I` to represent the imaginary unit. Let's say I pick `_I`. Then issue the command `interface(imaginaryunit= _I);`.

Answer (score 1):

$I$ as a name is protected in Maple, therefore you cannot use it. But there are other possibilities, for example you can declare a local name $I$ via

> **local** $I$ := ...

The imaginary unit is then still available via **_I**.

For a reference see the manual on [protected names](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/MapleSim/view.aspx?path=protect). Hope, that helped.

Answer (score 1):

If one should define some codes just for using $I$ as an alphabet, so what about using `I1` or `I2` instead. Indeed, by doing this, there is no need to change the meaning of $I$ in Maple.

Comment: $+1\ddot\smile$